# Load Controller Method inside Image src attribute

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have one controller method, which call when mail open and image attribute `src` is call.

**Here is my email content:**

```
<img src="http://localhost/b1g1/emailopenrate/3" alert=""  height="1px" width="1px">'
```

**Here I declare in route file like this:**

```
Route::get('/emailopenrate/{email_id}', 'FrontpublicController@getEmailopenrate');
```

And last I have `controller` method that will call on when mail is open and image load.

```
public function getEmailopenrate($email_id){

// code goes here.

}
```

Actually I want to email open rate based on image loading. When I send mail and open it, it can't not call any reason why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should give the link to the image as : < a href = "your_link"><img src="http://localhost/b1g1/emailopenrate/3" alert=""  height="1px" width="1px">'</a>

Comment: No way that's not possible becuase <a> not automatically loaded when mail open. @Drudge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not laravel issue. Basically you have to put live server url not your local url into `image` tage `src`.

**Example:**

URL will be: `<img src="http://example.com/emailopenrate/3">`

**not like this**

```
<img src="http://localhost/test/emailopenrate/3"/>
```